# Checking of Delaunay triangulation in 3D

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, meshing

One of the easy ways of checking Delaunay triangulation in 2D is to see if all the angles are acute or right angles. Do we have some kind of easy checking in 3D as well?

Comment: May be this could be of interest : https://www.kiv.zcu.cz/site/documents/verejne/vyzkum/publikace/technicke-zpravy/2002/tr-2002-02.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In 2D, no circumscribed circle of a triangle may contain another point. In 3D, no circumscribed sphere of a tetrahedron may contain another point.

Comment: Do we have any easy way of checking it? Like the acute angle case in 2d?